# Confuse about <Curve to mesh> node in Geometry Node

Tags: modeling, geometry-nodes

[image]

Hello,

I add two quadratic Beziers whose end vector is (2.0.0) and (0.3.0)and it forms a mesh along X&Z. It's acting strangely! Should not it be along the X&Y axis? I did not give it any vector on the Z-axis.

Can you help me solve this? I've attached a screenshot of what's happening.

Thanks!

————————————————————————————————————————————————————

[image: I have check for the rotation.]

Comment: You can probably change one or other of your bezier curves in a different direction [X, Y, Z] to meet some goal. Please show those investigations in a new screen capture.   That might only take only 38 minutes or less.  What is your goal with the geometry nodes above?  If people know your goal then they may provide a solution.  Please show as similar node system using the provided circle as a cross section and the result can be a tube.  Please state if such a system meets your expectation.

Comment: Is the object itself rotated?  Please show the rotation data in a screen capture.

Comment: I have checked the rotation, please see the screen capture !

Comment: I just want to clear about the logic behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the node `Curve to Mesh`, the following happens:

It uses the calculated local coordinate system of the main curve for the orientation of the profile curve, instead of the global coordinate system.

Primarily, this has to do with the fact that your main curve has its own "top", or local *Z-axis*, which results from the points of this curve (and can therefore vary greatly).

A curve starts at the first point and extends along all further points. This results in a vector that defines up direction of this curve per curve point. This is the local *Z-axis* or the *tangent* of the curve points.

This means:

The axes of the profile curve are aligned according to the rotation of the curve points of your main curve!

Thus a translation of the coordinate systems takes place.

Unfortunately, I cannot explain to you here completely exactly, how these axes are calculated, since here still other factors play with, but essentially the calculation is based on the [cross product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross_product) of the local *Z-axis* of the main curve (*tangent*) and the global *Z-axis*.

> **Note:** The value for the tilt of the curve also plays a crucial role. This value influences the rotation of the individual curve points again additionally and lets the local coordinate system rotate per point around the local *Z-axis*!

> Tip: If you always extrude the main curve into the *Z-axis*, it will be easier for you to keep track of these rotations, because then the whole coordinate system will not rotate in such an unpredictable way. If you end up needing a different rotation of the mesh, just apply the node `transform` afterwards.

Anyway, I've created an example for you that shows this behavior a little better and that you can experiment with further:

[image]

*(Red/Green/Blue = X/Y/Z of the main curve; Purple = direction of the profile curve (global); Yellow = rotation of the main curve applied to the direction of the profile curve).*

[image]